# Java resource as File

Tags: java, resources, classloader

Is there a way in Java to construct a `File` instance on a resource retrieved from a jar through the classloader?

My application uses some files from the jar (default) or from a filesystem directory specified at runtime (user input). I'm looking for a consistent way of
a) loading these files as a stream
b) listing the files in the user-defined directory or the directory in the jar respectively

Edit: Apparently, the ideal approach would be to stay away from `java.io.File` altogether. Is there a way to load a directory from the classpath and list its contents (files/entities contained in it)?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` and `Class.getResourceAsStream` are definitely the way to go for loading the resource data. However, I don't believe there's any way of "listing" the contents of an element of the classpath.

In some cases this may be simply impossible - for instance, a `ClassLoader` *could* generate data on the fly, based on what resource name it's asked for. If you look at the `ClassLoader` API (which is basically what the classpath mechanism works through) you'll see there isn't anything to do what you want.

If you know you've actually got a jar file, you could load that with `ZipInputStream` to find out what's available. It will mean you'll have different code for directories and jar files though.

One alternative, if the files are created separately first, is to include a sort of manifest file containing the list of available resources. Bundle that in the jar file or include it in the file system as a file, and load it before offering the user a choice of resources.

Comment: I agree it's annoying - but it makes ClassLoader more widely applicable in other ways. For instance, it's easy to write a "web classloader" because the web is good for fetching files, but it doesn't typically *list* files.

Comment: It seems like if the resource you are trying to load is much bigger than 1MiB the `InputStream` you get from `getResourceAsStream` stops to retrieve the bytes of the resource after that size and instead returns 0 iff it is contained in a compressed filesystem like a jar. You seem to be forced to use `getResource` and load the file independently from this in that case.

Comment: @mgttlinger: That sounds unlikely to me... probably worth posting a new question with a repro if you can.

Comment: The issue was due to the `read` method deciding how much data to read (I wasn't aware of that). And it seems that the whole file is read if the file being read is located in a regular folder. If the file is within a jar because it has been packaged it reads only parts of it.

Comment: @mgttlinger: No, it won't only read parts of it - but it might not fill the whole buffer provided on every read call. As always with `InputStream`, if you want to read the whole resource, you should loop until `read` returns -1.

Answer (score 109):

I had the same problem and was able to use the following:

```
// Load the directory as a resource
URL dir_url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(dir_path);
// Turn the resource into a File object
File dir = new File(dir_url.toURI());
// List the directory
String files = dir.list()
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work with JARs in classpath, only with files and directories

Comment: @yegor256 If your file is in a jar you can create a `FileSystem` object and get the `Path` from that. Then you can read it like usual. (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22605905/1876344)

Answer (score 57):

Here is a bit of code from one of my applications...
Let me know if it suits your needs.
You can use this if you know the file you want to use.

```
URL defaultImage = ClassA.class.getResource("/packageA/subPackage/image-name.png");
File imageFile = new File(defaultImage.toURI());
```

Comment: Yes ist does, but `toURI()` will fail.

Comment: This will fail if the resource is in a JAR file (on the classpath)

Comment: To be specific: If the resource is in a different JAR file than the code thats executing it.

Answer (score 19):

A reliable way to construct a File instance on a resource retrieved from a jar is it to copy the resource as a stream into a temporary File (the temp file will be deleted when the JVM exits):

```
public static File getResourceAsFile(String resourcePath) {
    try {
        InputStream in = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
        if (in == null) {
            return null;
        }

        File tempFile = File.createTempFile(String.valueOf(in.hashCode()), ".tmp");
        tempFile.deleteOnExit();

        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
            //copy stream
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
        return tempFile;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream ("some/pkg/resource.properties");
```

There are more methods available, e.g. see here: 
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know about getResourceAsStream, but I don't think I can load a directory from the classpath through that.

Comment: In Java directory is a file (UNIX roots I guess) so you should at least try.

Comment: I think to list files in a directory you are going to need to use java.io.File.  You can look up files with the ClassLoader.findResource which returns a URL that can be passed to File.

Answer (score 2):

This is one option: http://www.uofr.net/~greg/java/get-resource-listing.html

Comment: Whilst this link may answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference, as a link may change or the linked page may be removed, thereby making the answer useless.