# Unable to create File object for a file in Jar

Tags: java, jar, distribution

I am trying to include a number of text files as resources in my runnable .jar-file. The following code should print the contents of one file:

```
URI resourceFile = Driver.class.getResource("/etc/inputfile.txt").toURI();
System.out.println("Opening URI: " + resourceFile.toString());
File infile = new File(resourceFile);

Scanner sc = new Scanner(infile);
while (sc.hasNextLine())
    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
sc.close();
```

After exporting as a runnable jar, I get the following output when running:

> Opening URI: rsrc:etc/inputfile.txt
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
>             at java.io.File.(File.java:363)

The file can be printed without any problems if I use getResourceAsStream, but I'd like to use the File object for other reasons.
How can I resolve this?

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676097/java-resource-as-file or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403256/how-do-i-read-a-resource-file-from-a-java-jar-file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135427/uri-not-hierarchical-need-to-use-file-class-for-a-method/46135584?noredirect=1#comment79233689_46135584 may possibly help. I had similar problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A URI represents a "file" only when the scheme is `file:`. 
And the constructor [File(URI)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.net.URI%29) is clear on this.
You can't treat a packed file inside a jar as a File because... it just isn't what Java considers a `File`: read the definition of [what the File class represents](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

> An abstract representation of **file and
>   directory pathnames**.

The way to read is by `getResourceAsStream()`, as you said.

Comment: OK, thanks. Do you know of any open source framework that helps abstract this so I can treat files and jar streams alike?

Comment: I use `URL` (or URI) for this. It can be consider as a generalization that includes files (scheme `file:`)  and resources inside jars (scheme `jar:` ) as special cases.  But remember: a java `File` is conceptually just the path, think of it as the name of the file. It's the identifier of a resource (which is not necessarily opened, which perhaps even does not exist). Don't mix that concept with the content of the file. A stream is a content.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. java.io.File is an abstraction over paths and pathnames on a filesystem. You will need to stick in the URL domain if you want to reference files inside a JAR.