# How to set a icon for the java swing applciation?

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I am trying to set up icon for my java swing application with this code

```
setIconImage(new ImageIcon("logo.png").getImage());
```

but it is showing error on ImageIcon as cannot find symbol. Can anyone help me with a solution?

Comment: How to insert coding in my question ? I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: Please have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java resource as file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676097/java-resource-as-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `logo.png` file in the same package as the class that's calling it

```
ProjectRoot
         src
             MyClass.java
             logo.png
```

and use

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("logo.png"));
setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```

See [Load Image icon Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/2587435) for more details

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
setIconImage(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("logo.png").getPath()).getImage());
```

in this example `Main` is name of your class