# URI is not hierarchical - but I need a File object

Tags: java, lucene, uri, classloader

I need to get a File object (not a Stream) to pass to a library. I am getting "URI is not hierarchical". I have seen some solutions but they either are rather inefficient or use external libraries.

> File myFile = new File(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(dir).toURI())

By the way, I need the object to pass to

> Lucene FSDirectory.open(myFile)

Any idea?

Comment: What's the url actually look like?

Comment: Not sure, it is an issue in the server with PIG, when I run it on hadoop it works fine.

Comment: A basic debugging strategy is to print intermediate calculations out so you can inspect them.  Putting some logging statements in this routine with a log-level of "FINE" seems like a wise investment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java resource as file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676097/java-resource-as-file)

Answer (score 0):

[URI not hierarchical need to use File class for a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135427/uri-not-hierarchical-need-to-use-file-class-for-a-method/46135584?noredirect=1#comment79233689_46135584)

may be a possible solution. Essentially just copies the file to a temp file then uses that. I was getting this error since I was using a JAR.