# URI not hierarchical need to use File class for a method

Tags: java

I need to open a video file with my code, and it works perfectly fine in Eclipse but when I export into a runnable JAR, i get an error "URI not hierarchical".

I have seen people suggest using getResourceAsStream(), but i need to have a file object as i am using Desktop.getDesktop.open(File). Can anyone help me out?

Here is the code:

```
try {
    URI path1 = getClass().getResource("/videos/tutorialVid1.mp4").toURI();
    File f = new File(path1);

    Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

if it helps my folder list is like

- Src

  - videos

    - videoFile.mp4

EDIT:
I plan to run this on windows only, and use launch4j to create an exe.

Comment: A resource inside a jar file is not a file. It doesn't live in the filesystem. So you can't use a File to refer to it, since it is not a file.

Comment: Is there another method i can use then? b/c all I care about is being able to play the video without using external APIs or JMF.

Comment: Don't put the video inside the jar file. Bundle it with your application, but outside the jar file. Or read it fro the jar file, copy it to a temporary file, and open that temporary file.

Comment: Could you link to an example for the second one? Please and Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just google for "how to create a temporary file in Java"? You'll have plenty of links, without needing my help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the file from the jar to a temporary file and open that.

Here's a method to create a temporary file for a given jar resource:

```
public static File createTempFile(String path) {
    String[] parts = path.split("/");
    File f = File.createTempFile(parts[parts.length - 1], ".tmp");
    f.deleteOnExit();
    try (Inputstream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path))  {
        Files.copy(in, f.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
    return f;
}
```

And here's an example of how you'd use it:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(createTempFile("/videos/tutorialVid1.mp4"));
```

Comment: Tip: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-

Comment: Is using .mp4 instead of .tmp ok as well? or is it dangerous/bad practice?

Comment: @shadowforce100 Yes, that would be fine as well.

Comment: I just noticed that for some reason the temp file was not deleted so StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING needs to be a third parameter. Fixed

Comment: Are you sure it's not deleted? The call to `deleteOnExit` should have the JVM delete the file on shutdown.

Comment: I was getting an exception that it already exists... java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: then the file path to the temp file