# Exporting Jar with Images

Tags: java, image, jar, export, exe

I am trying to export my Runnable Jar file that includes the image resources that goes along with my program.  When I run the program in eclipse the paths work perfectly but when trying to export the program there are no images. I have been exporting by choosing the package all contents option.

[image: This is my Folder Structure]

[image: This is how I locate the file]

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635636/eclipse-exported-runnable-jar-not-showing-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your image files are stored in jar as resources you should retrieve them as resources. Hers is [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676097/java-resource-as-file)