# How do you create a .jar file for an applet that has images and sound?

Tags: java, jar, compilation, applet, embedded-resource

I am creating a Simon Says memory sequence game that is created in Java Applet. I need to post it on a website and just be able to run it without using a java compiler. It has an Image folder and a Sound folder that need to be included in the .jar file.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/kwolff7/SimonSays/tree/master) to some code.

Comment: Those resources have become embedded resources once put into a Jar.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form a URL to an embedded resource.  It will probably help to prefix every string with `/`. Then the `getImage(URL)` method can load the resource from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pack all necessary files to this jar and use them as resources not files. See how it's done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676097/java-resource-as-file).

Comment: Given that Q&A is all about streams, whereas applets work well with URLs, I don't see it as being strongly relevant to this question..

Comment: @AndrewThompson OP says: "Sound folder that need to be included in the .jar file" - that's the reason I had suggested to use these files as resources and so as streams.

Comment: URLs can work for Jar files as well.  ;)  Note that among the [applet methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#method.summary), there is `getImage(URL)` and `getImage(URL, String)`, but no `getImage(InputStream)`.  Of course, there are a number of other ways to load images from streams, but in my comment on the question, I recommended sticking with an URL for the sake of continuing to use the inbuilt applet methods.